# json data throwing error as "TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'"

Tags: python, rest

I have this data and when I run the script i get the error as "  "guid": "Internal" TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'"

Here is my code, the other dictionaries in the data work fine, but only the last one has problems.
Can someone tell me the correct syntax please.

```
import requests
headers = {
        'Authorization': 'FortifyToken MmRjODVjZjctOWE2Zi00NGQxLWFkZTAtZmE2ZjUxZmZiYmU1',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Accept': 'application/json'
}

json_data = {
[
    {
        "guid": "DevPhase",
        "attributeDefinitionId": "5578",
        "values": [
        {
        "guid": "Active"
        }
        ]
    },

    {
        "guid": "Accessibility",
        "attributeDefinitionId": "5590",
        "values": [
        {
        "guid": "externalpublicnetwork"
        }
        ]
    },

    {
        "guid": "DevStrategy",
        "attributeDefinitionId": "5583",
        "values": [
        {
        "guid": "Internal"
        }
        ]
        }
]
}

url="http://localhost:8080/ssc/api/v1/projectVersions/6855/attributes"
response = requests.put(url, headers=headers, json=json_data)
print(response.status_code)
print(response.json())
```

Comment: Your problem is not the last one. That is just where the problem is being reported. This assignment `json_data = {[ ... ]}` is assigning a set.  There is only element in the set, and that is a list. A list cannot be an element of a set, because set elements must be hashable and a list is not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not insert an array to an object directly. You should use a key.

```
json_data = [
    {
        "guid": "DevPhase",
        "attributeDefinitionId": "5578",
        "values": [
        {
        "guid": "Active"
        }
        ]
    },

    {
        "guid": "Accessibility",
        "attributeDefinitionId": "5590",
        "values": [
        {
        "guid": "externalpublicnetwork"
        }
        ]
    },

    {
        "guid": "DevStrategy",
        "attributeDefinitionId": "5583",
        "values": [
        {
        "guid": "Internal"
        }
        ]
        }
]
```

Try with this.